# Concatenation and Not Exists Operation

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have two tables and I want all the records from tb1 to be inserted over to tb2 the values from tb1 are CXR1,CXR2 and CXR3 since CXR2 is already in tb2 only two records which are CXR1 and CXR3 will be inserted to tb2 using NOT EXISTS operation, however; I need also those records will be concatenated e.g. CXR1;CXR3 and save it over to col Action...

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ABC_TBL (ID,DESC,ACTION)
                                        SELECT @ID,DESC,@ACTION
                                        FROM XYZ_TBL
                                        WHERE XYZ_TBL.TYPE=@TYPE AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID,DESC,ACTION FROM ABC_TBL 
                    WHERE ID=@ID AND ABC_TBL.DESC=XYZ_TBL.DESC)"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Textbox1.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Textbox2.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACTION", SqlDbType.VarChar,255).Value = The Value should be CXR1;CXR3 the added not exists value in concatenation 

Originating Table
    XYZ_TBL
    TYPE    DESC 
    A       CXR1
    B       ALC
    C       ADB
    A       CXR2
    B       ALC1
    C       ADB1
    A       CXR3

Destination Table    
    ABC_TBL    
    ID  DESC    TYPE    ACTION
    123 CXR1    A       CXR1;CXR3
    123 CXR3    A       CXR1;CXR3

Existing Record   
    ABC_TBL    
    ID  DESC    TYPE    ACTION
    123 CXR2    A       CXR2
```

Comment: Hi @DaleK, my apologies. Felt awkward as the texts are not in good place they are all over the place...

Comment: @DaleK sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does what you ask:

```
declare @XYZ_TBL table ([TYPE] char(1), [DESC] varchar(4));
declare @ABC_TBL table (ID int, [DESC] varchar(4), [TYPE] char(1), [ACTION] varchar(64));

insert into @XYZ_TBL ([TYPE], [DESC])
values ('A',       'CXR1')
, ('B',       'ALC')
, ('C',       'ADB')
, ('A',       'CXR2')
, ('B',       'ALC1')
, ('C',       'ADB1')
, ('A',       'CXR3');

insert into @ABC_TBL (ID, [DESC], [TYPE], [ACTION])
values (123, 'CXR2',    'A',       'CXR2');

declare @Type char(1) = 'A', @Id int = 123;

with cte as (
  SELECT @ID id, [DESC], [TYPE]
  FROM @XYZ_TBL T
  WHERE T.[TYPE] = @TYPE
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ID, [DESC], [ACTION]
    FROM @ABC_TBL A
    WHERE ID = @ID
    AND T.[DESC] like A.[DESC]
  )
)
INSERT INTO @ABC_TBL (ID, [DESC], [TYPE], [ACTION])
select @ID, [DESC], [TYPE]
  , (select string_agg([DESC], ';') from cte)
from cte C1;

select * from @ABC_TBL;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=58d0c9d1109c2b0c5b81012d24fbc4c7)

NOTE: If you set the data up in your question as I have done here people will be much quicker to assist because its much less work for them.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'm getting an error "syntax near from"

Comment: It works in SQL Server when I transfer it to VB.NET I'm getting a syntax error. Anyway, I'll study the code and If I cannot figure out, I'll ask your help again. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to do it. Thank you so much. You've been a great help.

Comment: Hi @Dale K, it took me for so long to notice that the data is not sorted out, tried to put order by after cte but it does not work   (select string_agg([DESC], ';') from cte order by [DESC]

Comment: I was able to sort it out...(select string_agg([DESC], ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY [DESC]) from cte)